# Backbone to listen to remote changes to collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am new to Backbone and building an application as my first try at using the framework.

The application is a calendar that allows the calendar owner to publish a calendar and others to book appointments which are stored in a single collection on the server.

When users load the calendar, the backbone app instantiates and fetches the collection displaying all the available appointments in the view.

This means that multiple users can each view the same calendar on different machines, each from a different instance of the backbone app but each app running off the same remote collection.

My problem is that i need changes to the remote collection triggered by one user to be immediately available to any other active instance of the application in another browser.

Obviously, collection change events will be fired WITHIN each instance of the app when one user books an appointment but these wont be fired ACROSS all instances of the calendar running else where. So in other words i need remote changes to the collection triggered OUTSIDE of the app instance to be picked up by the app.

The only way i can think to do this is use a setInterval to continually poll the remote collection, either running a full fetch, or better still somehow checking if the remote collection differs to the local one, and updating the collection and re-rendering the view, but this seems a bit hackish and not how BB, as an event-driven framework, is meant to be used.

I wanted to ask if anyone else had ever solved this same problem of BB instances needing to listen to remote collection changes triggered outside the app, and if so how you dealt with it? I have already searched SO and not found answers to this in particular because I'm not even sure on the terminology to describe the problem.

Comment: You might want to look at how MeteorJS has achieved this or even use MeteorJS instead, because other than the poor-man's polling solution you mentioned it can get quite tricky to synchronise like that and solutions depends on what tech and database you are using in the backend.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I will take a look at Meteor and I'm also thinking Web Sockets might be the way to go here and will look into this also.